# How will you extract flavour details from these product URLs (give either logic or formula)

Tags: excel, url, excel-formula, extract, cut

I have a bunch of URls, and I have to extract flavour details (by excel formula or provide other logic):

- recipes/caprese-chicken-foil-pack/2ac1725a-72b9-4ff1-9337-1d8c809b5db0/
- /recipes/cheesy-chicken-sausage-and-potatoes-foil-pack/298f643a-84ac-4a7e-8d59-912c2dec05c3/
- /recipes/cheesy-chicken-sausage-and-potatoes-foil-pack/298f643a-84ac-4a7e-8d59-912c2dec05c3/
- /recipes/grilled-banana-boats/09e8e5bb-c44e-4111-8af1-8b1cf8a182f5/
- /recipes/seasoned-sage-grilled-potato-pack/2e6d2280-b47b-468f-943d-eb87a37cf709/

My formula is: `=IFERROR(MID(B12;FIND("/";B12;2)+1;FIND("foil";B12;1)-FIND("/";B12;2)-2);MID(B12;FIND("/";B12;2)+1;FIND("pack";B12;1)-FIND("/";B12;2)-2))`

But it fail when I have *foil* or *packs* at the end

Would you provide with ideas? Thanx

Comment: What would be your output from given sample data?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=LET(X,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[preceding::*[1]='recipes']")&"-pack-foil-",LEFT(X,MIN(FIND({"-pack-","-foil-"},X)-1)))
```

More on `FILTERXML()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194).

Comment: thanx for prompt reply

Answer (score 0):

Step by step to get the recipes names:
urls in column A
In cell B1
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-7-FIND("recipes/",A1,1))
In cell C1
=LEFT(B1,FIND("/",B1,1)-1)
In cell D1
=SUBSTITUTE(C1,"-"," ")